# Unable to make connection to mongodb atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to connect to a mongo atlas db. I have copy and pasted the string but get this MongoNetworkError that I do not understand. What could be causing this? Is there a way I can get more info on it?

```
mongoose.connect("{copy pasted string from atlas with my password replaced here}")
```

This is what the terminal spits out

```
: 1): MongoNetworkError: connection 4 to {mydbonatlas} closed
```

I am using mongodb 3.4.x

Two things I am suspicous of:

1) Work place VPN may be blocking it?

2) incorrect password because when I put some gibberish password I get the same message. Though I changed the password and tried it again multiple times to make sure it is correct

EDIT: I just connected to it using Robo 3T. It connects using Robo 3T but not from my code.

Comment: try to connect first using robo3t, it's even easier to debug connection issues ?

Comment: It connect on robo3t

Comment: If it works using robo3t so i think we could eliminate the first option 1), since the robo3t also has used the same network ?

Comment: Yes. Same network. Then it's something wrong with my connection string? I just don't know what..

Comment: The error is gone. I don't know why... I changed nothing except connected with Robo 3t

Comment: I think maybe, but what about if you try to connect the same way but with local mongodb ?

Comment: very strange! but good for you.